# Running MPI code in embarrassingly parallel (on PBS-Torque cluster)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, pbs, torque

I have written an MPI based C-code that I use to perform numerical simulations in parallel. Due to some poor design on my part, I have built in some inherent MPI dependencies into the code (array structures, MPI-IO). This means that if I want to run my code in serial, I have to invoke

```
mpiexec -n 1 c_exe
```

**Main problem** 
I use my C code within a Python workflow that is simplified in the loop below.

```
import os 
import subprocess

homedir = os.getenv('PBS_O_WORKDIR')

nevents = 100
for ievent in range(nevents):

    perform_workflow_management()
    os.chdir(ievent)
    subprocess.call('mpiexec -n 1 c_exe', Shell=True)
    os.chdir(homedir)
```

The Python workflow is primarily for management and makes calls to the C code which performs the numerically intensive work.

The tasks within the Python for loop are independent, consequently I would like to employ an embarrassingly parallel scheme to parallelize the loop over events. Benchmarks indicate that parallelizing the loop over events will be faster than a serial loop with parallel MPI calls. Furthermore, I am running this on a PBS-Torque cluster.

I am at a loss about how to do this effectively. The complication seems to arise due to MPI call to my C code and the assignment of multiple MPI tasks.

**Things I have tried in some form**

Wrappers to pbsdsh - incur problems with processor assignment.

MPMD with mpiexec - Theoretically does what I would like but fails because all processes seem to share MPI_COMM_WORLD. My C code establishes a cartesian topology for domain based parallelism; conflicts arise here.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I might achieve deploy this in an embarrassingly parallel fashion? Ideally I would like to submit a job request

```
qsub -l nodes=N:ppn=1,walltime=XX:XX:XX go_python_job.bash
```

where N is the number of processors. On each process I would then like to be able to submit independent mpiexec calls to my C code.

I'm aware that part of the issue is down to design flaws but if I could find a solution without having to refactor large parts of code that would be advantageous.

Comment: 1) How many "events" / time per event are we talking? It might just be feasible to just launch a job per event (via python) - exposing the maximal amount of parallelism to the batch system. This way you get the best back-fill - but you may overload the batch system. 2) Have you tried just replacing all instances of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` with `MPI_COMM_SELF` except for the intial workflow management?

Comment: So events are typically on the order of 100's and each C call can take ~10 minutes for a typical problem size (run in serial). I haven't tried MPI_COMM_SELF although it seems that could be a solution. If I ran MPMD as follows  `mpiexec -n 1 a.out : -n 1 b.out`, and replaced `MPI_COMM_WORLD` with `MPI_COMM_SELF` would each instance only access the ranks on which it was launched?

Comment: Are multiple jobs per node possible on your cluster, or do you always block a full node even if you request only one core?

Comment: I believe multiple jobs per node are possible. I tested a version with MPI_COMM_SELF and MPMD dispatch using mpiexec. Things seemed to work as desired. The mpiexec assigns different nodes and the MPI_COMM_SELF acts to 'serialize' the MPI code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, with any decent MPI implementation you don't have to use `mpiexec` to start a singleton MPI job - simply run the executable (MPI standard, §10.5.2 Singleton MPI_INIT). It works at least with Open MPI and the MPICH family.

Second, any decent DRM (distributed resource manager, a.k.a. batch queueing system) supports array jobs. Those are the DRM equivalent of SPMD - multiple jobs with the same job file.

To get an array job with Torque, pass `qsub` the `-t from-to` option, either on the command line or in the job script:

```
#PBS -t 1-100
...
```

Then, in your Python script obtain the value of the `PBS_ARRAYID` environment variable and use it to differentiate between the different instances:

```
import os 
import subprocess

homedir = os.getenv('PBS_O_WORKDIR')
ievent = os.getenv('PBS_ARRAYID')

perform_workflow_management()
os.chdir(ievent)
subprocess.call('./c_exe', Shell=True)
os.chdir(homedir)
```

As already mentioned by @Zulan, this allows the job scheduler to better exploit the resources of the cluster via backfilling (if your Torque instance is paired with Maui or similar advanced scheduler).

The advantage of array jobs is that although from your perspective they look and work (mostly) like a single job the scheduler still sees them as separate jobs and schedule them individually.

One possible disadvantage of this approach is that if jobs are scheduled exclusively, i.e. no two jobs could share a single compute node, then the utilisation will be quite low unless your cluster nodes have just one single-core CPU each (very unlikely nowadays).

Comment: Interesting to know that `Singleton MPI_INIT` is part of the standard. I did not want to suggest a solution that omits `mpiexec` that is purely implementation dependent.

Comment: This is useful. I had managed to run ./c_exe without mpiexec in the past but was unaware of the rules relating to `Singleton MPI_INIT`. In this way MPI_COMM_WORLD is set to the single process and my code runs fine. As for the job array, I had avoided this because it involves submitting a series of jobs to a queue. For my workflow I request my nodes upfront and then proceed to assign tasks to the nodes from within the workflow (runs on a master node). If I were to use a singleton MPI call would a scheme that invokes pbsdsh seem reasonable?